# graphical method in game theory

Tags: game-theory, operations-research

Solve graphically the following game:

$\begin{array}{ccc}
&&B1&B2 
\end{array}
\\
\begin{array}{c}
A1\\
A2\\
A3
\end{array}
\left[
 \begin{array} {cc}
3&-2 \\
-1&4 \\
2 &2 
\end{array}
\right ]$

I have solved the question graphically and got two intersection points. The reduced matrix for both points are:

$\begin{array}{ccc}
&&B1&B2 
\end{array}
\\
\begin{array}{c}
A2\\
A3
\end{array} 
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
-1&4 \\
2&2 
\end{array}
\right]$

and

$
\begin{array}{ccc}
&&B1&B2 
\end{array}
\\
\begin{array}{c}
A1\\
A3
\end{array} \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
3&-2 \\
2&2 
\end{array}
\right]$

By using the probabilistic approach I got the value of the game to be 2 for both and strategy of A to be (0,0,1) for both points and strategy of B to be ($\frac{2}{5},\frac{3}{5}$) and ($\frac{4}{5},\frac{1}{5}$) respectively for the two points.

Later I realised both the reduced matrix have a saddle point. The value of game for both turn out to be 2 and best strategies for each point to be A3,B1 and A3,B2 respectively for each point.

Now I am confused which approach is correct. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Is this a zero sum game, or is the number  $a_{ij}$ the payoff to both players if Row chooses $i$ and column chooses $j$?

Comment: the payoff $a_{ij}$ is the gain of A and loss of B if A adopts $i^th$ strategy and B adopts $j^th$ strategy. It is zero sum.